# top-level modal dialog to cover whole angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

i would like to implement a login dialog using a modal (from angular-ui-bootstrap project).
It should lay over the whole application, cover it in the backdrop and should be able to be raised as soon as a AngularJS service sets a variable to false.

I don't like to use routing to a login page because i'd like to keep input values in the application.

How could you watch the variable and trigger the open()-function of the modal dialog properly?

EDIT: I'm using Thrift for communicating with the server, so watching for $http Status Codes is generally not easy in my case...

Comment: You got three answers so far, choose one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this. Since the modal is a service itself, you could really just call open directly from your service. Alternatively, the service could publish an event which something could listen on and trigger the login page.

If you really want to watch a specific variable (because it might be changed from different places), you could setup a $watch on the $rootScope that then calls open.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [angular-ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) module and use it's $modal service to show a login modal without redirecting to any other page.

You can find an implementation of the same in angular-app demo apps security service -

https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/common/security/security.js

Comment: I think he's already saying that he is using the modal service from angular-ui-bootstrap, he's just asking for ways to trigger it from his service.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use events for this. The trick is to watch for unsuccessful service calls assuming your backend let the request fail and is sending the correct status for access denied (403). The flag `$rootScope.isLoggingIn` is to prevent multiple LoginDialogs to appear, when there is more than one call in the chain.

**Untested code** was from my mind, so **please test** it and correct in case of errors / typos

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
</html>
```

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap.modal'])
.run(function($rootScope, $modal) {
    $rootScope.isLoggingIn = false;
    $rootScope.$on('showLoginDialogEvent', function (e, evtArgs) {
        $rootScope.isLoggingIn = true;
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'views/loginView.html', 
            controller: 'LoginDialogController'})
        .result.then(function(){
             $rootScope.isLoggingIn = false;
        });
    }
});
```

```
angular.module('requestInterceptor', [])
.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('RequestInterceptor');
})
.factory('RequestInterceptor', function ($q, $rootScope) {
    return {
        'request': function (config) {
            return config || $q.when(config);
        },

        'requestError': function(rejection) {
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        },

        'response': function(response) {
            return response || $q.when(response);
        },

        'responseError': function(rejection) {
            if(!$rootScope.isLoggingIn && rejection.status === 403)
               $rootScope.$broadcast('showLoginDialogEvent');
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    }
}
```

angular >= 1.2.0

angular-ui.bootstrap >= 0.7

Comment: I'm using Thrift for communicating with the server, so watching for $http Status Codes is generally not easy in my case...